# two function addresses subtraction

Tags: c, function, subtraction

I'm reading a piece of code about exploit in [here](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/9488/). There is a statement going like this:

```
/*
FreeBSD <= 6.1 suffers from classical check/use race condition on SMP
systems in kevent() syscall, leading to kernel mode NULL pointer
dereference. It can be triggered by spawning two threads:
1st thread looping on open() and close() syscalls, and the 2nd thread
looping on kevent(), trying to add possibly invalid filedescriptor. 
*/

static void kernel_code(void) {
    struct thread *thread;
    gotroot = 1;
    asm(
        "movl %%fs:0, %0"
        : "=r"(thread)
    );
    thread->td_proc->p_ucred->cr_uid = 0;
#ifdef PRISON_BREAK
    thread->td_proc->p_ucred->cr_prison = NULL;
#endif
    return;
}

static void code_end(void) {
return;
}

int main() {
....
memcpy(0, &kernel_code, &code_end - &kernel_code);
....
}
```

I'm curious what's the meaning of this `memcpy`? What is the result of `&code_end - &kernel_code`?

Comment: Where is `memset`, I do not see it. As for the pointer arithmetic, it is copying something into the buffer.

Comment: Did you mean `memcpy()`? Because I can see no `memset()`. OK I see your edit, good question, +1.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I'm sorry, I made a misspelling. I have edited it.

Comment: @t0mm13b I'm sorry, I made a misspelling. I have edited it.

Comment: @gsamaras I'm sorry, I made a misspelling. I have edited it.

Comment: There's explanation in the linked post. Please copy it here as it is really *relevant*.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Ok, I'll do that.

Comment: It's using a gcc extension that allows arithmetic on function pointers. It is basically subtracting the address of the `code_end` function from the address of the `kernel_code` function, and the code is assuming that to be the length of the `kernel_code` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes that the function `kernel_code()` will end <del>where</del> *somewhere before* function `code_end()` starts.  The `memcpy()` therefore copies `kernel_code()` to address 0.  One assumes that some other aspect of the exploit results in a return or jump to address 0, thereby running `kernel_code()`.

Comment: Well, technically it only assumes it precedes `code_end`.

Answer (score 0):

```
void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );
```

That `memcpy` will copy the function `kernel_code` to address `0` (`NULL`).

Comment: Well, it's like `memcpy(0, &kernel_code, sizeof( function kernel_code))`

Answer (score 0):

What the code is trying to exploit, is gaining root privilege, UID of 0, by two threads competing for the queue, `do_thread`/`do_thread2`.

By `mmap`ing the contents of the address of the `code_end` function, with the address of `kernel_code`, copy the result into the buffer, to the address 0, on the condition that the code are adjacent to each other, thereby, as in effective user id of 0 aka root.

This [C++ Ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/?kw=memcpy) page summarizes what `memcpy` is about.

```
void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );
```

> Copies the values of num bytes from the location pointed to by source
>   directly to the memory block pointed to by destination.